# How to get active installs, total installs from google/apple stores?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I have deployed my app on google and apple store. I want some statistics like daily install, active install, uninstalled, rating and review for my analytical purpose from both stores. Right now I get that data from "app annie", but I need native api, so I can fetch data and store in my database. Can someone suggest me api related document/tutorial for the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the iOS console, but Google Play Developer Console offers all that natively.

> I want some statistics like daily install, active install, uninstalled...

Open the app you want to see in the console.

This is all available under the "Statistics" menu(option one). There are many options, but you can see active installs, total installs, uninstalls(shows day to day so you can see daily uninstalls),

> rating and review for my analytical purpose from both stores.

Make sure the app you want to see is opened in the console.

Select "Rating and review" option(number three). Under this menu you can see the average rating and how many has given your app x stars. However, you cannot see reviews that only are stars. You can filter reviews by stars as well meaning you only see reviews with text and x stars that you select.

You can also see basic details from the main menu(active installs, total installs, rating, crashes):

[image]
[Source](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-v-XUri6SGaY/U9PbYdHaMiI/AAAAAAABPoE/-4ieUkbm1bk/s1600/Screenshot+from+2014-07-26+23:55:08.png)

You can also [download the statistics, reviews and more](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

For Android play store you can use this utility - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

example - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en